# Voltage of a sine wave given max wattage rating

Tags: power-supply, speakers, watts, electromagnetic

I would like to test a speaker by giving a sine wave of 200 Hz. On the technical datasheet following are mentioned

Sine Wave : 30W

Maximum music load : 60 W

Frequency Range : 40 to 2000 Hz

Impedance : 8Ω

What should be my voltage and current of the sine wave ? Ensuring safe operation.

Comment: What is the nominal impedance of the speaker in ohms? It should be in the datasheet too. If you're lucky there might even be a curve for the impedance vs. frequency in the datasheet. You should also link to the datasheet, if possible.

Comment: Its 8Ω.Sry, I do not have any link to the product description.

Comment: So its ~15V P=V^2/R ?

Comment: Yes. The current is a dependent variable in this case: I=V/R. You could measure it see if the impedance is actually 8 ohms... The nominal value is a bit of a marketing. At a given frequency it could be less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$\sqrt{30W * 8ohm}= 15.5V\$. Don't hit it with 15.5V right away if possible, i.e. start a little lower and increase.

EDIT: Some clarifications merged here (from my various comments spread around the page) for the benefit of future readers:

- The voltage calculated above is RMS. This is usually the case when dealing with AC power requirements; more on how it relates to peak-to-peak voltage etc. can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude#Definitions_of_the_term
- For a set voltage, the current is a dependant variable by Ohm's law I = V/R. The current calculated from an RMS voltage would also be an RMS value. For devices like speakers, which actually have an non-constant impedance vs. frequency, it's not a bad idea to measure the current when applying a set voltage because the actual impedance at the chosen test frequency may turn out to be different than the single value that gets published/imprinted as the nominal impedance. Some (typically high-end) speaker come with an impedance-vs-frequency curve in their documentation. For others you may find it in some quality review, [e.g. it could look like this](http://www.stereophile.com/content/athena-technologies-f2-loudspeaker-measurements).
- The "music power" is higher than the sine power, twice in this case, because the [typical speaker testing standards](http://www.jblpro.com/pub/technote/spkpwfaq.pdf) call for a music-simulating test signal with a [crest factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor) of 6dB. A sine wave has a crest factor of only 3dB, which makes it twice as powerful on average than the 6dB-crest "music power"; a square wave would be even more so, having a 0dB crest factor.

Comment: 15.5 V Peak to Peak right ?

Comment: No! RMS. Voltage peaks should be at +-1.41*Vrms = +-21.855, so peak-to-peak voltage is twice the peaks, 43.71V in this case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude#Definitions_of_the_term if you need a diagram for that.

Comment: Another additional query for this problem. I will give 30V peak to peak (just to be on safe side) at 200 Hz. But my function generator has 50Ohms of output impedance. So thats 58Ohms of load. In what way(circuit / function generator) should I apply signal to the speaker so that I can get close to the maximum displacement of the membrane ?

Comment: You should really use an actual audio amplifier (current buffer) between your function generator and such a low impedance load like a speaker. An audio amplifier will have a much lower output impedance (under one ohm typically) than your signal generator. The reason is further detailed at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130414/low-output-impedance-vs-high-output-impedance-of-an-amplifier?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If the impedance is 8 ohms, the voltage to get 30 watts is 15.5 volts RMS. The current would be 15.5/8 or 1.9 amperes RMS. This is for a sine wave which is continuous.  The sine wave is worst case because it is always on at full amplitude.  The music rating is higher because music will vary considerably in amplitude with only relatively short peaks reaching full power.

Comment: Actually, square wave would be the worst case.

Comment: You are correct about the explanation for the music rating. It has an assumed [crest factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor) of 6dB in most speaker standards (of which there are several unfortunately), whereas a sine wave  a crest factor of only 3dB and a square wave has 0dB crest factor.